# bot in discord.py cannot create role

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot that creates a role when someone sends a message. For some reason, It keeps saying 'ctx' is not defined. How would I fix this error?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    server=ctx.message.server
    perms=discord.Permissions(administrator=true)
    await client.create_role(server,name='testrole', colour=discord.Colour(0x0000FF),permissions=perms)
```

when i change

```
async def on_message(message):
```

to

```
async def on_message(ctx):
```

it says 'message' is not defined.
I do not understand how I could define both of these because when I add the undefined part as shown below, It still says 'ctx' is not defined or 'message' is not defined.

```
async def on_message(message,ctx):
```

```
async def on_message(ctx,message):
```

update: I didn't have (pass_context=True) but now I know more

Comment: Do you know which version of the discord.py library you are using?

Comment: `on_message` does not have `ctx` . `ctx` . You can get the guild (not server) or the channel for the `message` object. Also read the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    guild=message.guild
    perms=discord.Permissions(administrator=True)
    await guild.create_role(name='testrole', colour=discord.Colour(0x0000FF),permissions=perms)
```

P.S. your bot need some permissions to create this Role.